# Missing columns when trying to groupby aggregate multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with relevant info, and I want to groupby one column, say id, with the other columns of the same id joined by "|". However, when I run my code, most of my columns end up missing (only the first 3 appear), and I don't know what is going wrong.

My code is:

```py
df = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda col: '|'.join(set(col))).reset_index()
```

For instance, my data starts like

```py
  id   words    ... (other columns here)
0  a     asd
1  a     rtr
2  b       s
3  c  rrtttt
4  c    dsfd
```

and I want

```py
id               ... (other columns here)
a        asd|rtr
b              s
c    rrtttt|dsfd
```

but also with all the rest of my columns grouped similarly. Right now the rest of my columns just don't appear in my output dataset. Not sure what is going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: probably because the other columns are not string type. You can try replace `'|'.join(set(col)))` with `'|'.join(set(col.astype(str))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to string beforehand, you can then avoid the lambda by using `agg(set)` and `applymap` after:

```
df.astype(str).groupby('id').agg(set).applymap('|'.join)
```

---

**Minimal Verifiable Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
   'numbers': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
   'words': ['asd', 'rtr', 's', 'rrtttt', 'dsfd']})
df

  id  numbers   words
0  a        1     asd
1  a        2     rtr
2  b        2       s
3  c        3  rrtttt
4  c        3    dsfd

df.astype(str).groupby('id').agg(set).applymap('|'.join)

   numbers        words
id                     
a      1|2      asd|rtr
b        2            s
c        3  rrtttt|dsfd
```